# Почему не прекращается цикл?

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции

Решаю следующую задачу:

**Задача**: Программа вводит с клавиатуры пару (число и строку) и выводит их на экран.
**Новая задача**: Программа вводит с клавиатуры пары (число и строку), сохраняет их в `HashMap`. Пустая строка – конец ввода данных. Числа могут повторяться. Строки всегда уникальны. Введенные данные не должны потеряться!
Затем программа выводит содержание `HashMap` на экран
Пример ввода:\

```
1
Мама
2
Рама
```

Пример вывода:

```
1 Мама
2 Рама
1 Мама
```

В примере кода, который я представил ниже, цикл почему-то не прекращает свою работу при вводе Enter, хотя по идее должен. В чём может быть проблема?

```
public static class task26 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Map<String, Integer> map = createMap();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Номер строки: " + pair.getValue() + ", строка:" + pair.getKey());
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> createMap()  {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите сначала целое число, а потом строку.");
        for (;true; System.out.println("Введите сначала целое число, а потом строку или завершите работу, нажав энтер.")) {
            int value = scanner.nextInt();
            String key = scanner.nextLine();
            map.put(key, value);
            if (key.isEmpty() || Integer.toString(value).isEmpty()) {
                map.remove(key);
                break;
            }
            }
        return map;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем варианте кода, программа завершает работу после ввода первой же цифры.
Вы когда вводите целое число и нажимаете Enter, вы передаете в программу не только число, а число + символ перевода строчки \n. Соответственно вы в value записываете целое число, а в key вы записываете символ \n. Добавив строку  **scanner.nextLine();**  можно "съесть" лишний символ перевода строки.

Код ниже:

```
public  class task26 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Map<String, Integer> map = createMap();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Номер строки: " + pair.getValue() + ", строка:" + pair.getKey());
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> createMap()  {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите сначала целое число, а потом строку.");
        for (;true; System.out.println("Введите сначала целое число, а потом строку или завершите работу, нажав энтер.")) {
            int value = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine(); // СЪЕСТЬ ЛИШНИЙ ПЕРЕВОД СТРОКИ
            String key = scanner.nextLine();
            map.put(key, value);
            if (key.isEmpty() || Integer.toString(value).isEmpty()) {
                map.remove(key);
                break;
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Консоль

```
Введите сначала целое число, а потом строку.
1
Мама
Введите сначала целое число, а потом строку или завершите работу, нажав энтер.
2
Рама
Введите сначала целое число, а потом строку или завершите работу, нажав энтер.
1

Номер строки: 2, строка:Рама
Номер строки: 1, строка:Мама

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Кроме того, у вас в задании описан выход из цикла как ввод пустой строки. Зачем вы проверяете пустое ли значение value для выхода из цикла? Тем более с помощью scanner.nextInt(); вы не сможете ввести пустую строку, ведь программа будет ожидать от вас INTEGER значение

Comment: С переводом строки я понял...
Но вот что с окончанием цикла по нажатию Enter? 
Ведь даже если не проверять value, с таким вот кодом:
if (key.isEmpty()) {
                    map.remove(key);
                    break;
                }
Всё равно почему-то цикл не завершается при вводе пустой строки...

Comment: ну в варианте который я прикрепил - цикл завершает свою работу, при нажатии Enter, когда программа ждет Строку. Все как в условии написано

Comment: Всё, я понял, спасибо большое, вы очень помогли!